# Create one loading form and load different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created one loading form, but I want access the loading form and load the different form. I know there is a way to achieve this, but the way that I think is create another loading form and access that another loading form to load the different form, even though the loading form contents are same.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the code of Loading Form:

```
public Loading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.timer1.Interval = SystemManager.RandomNumberGenerator(1000, 2000);

        this.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(this.CheckTimer);
    }

    private void Loading_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

    private void CheckTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uint timeLeft = 1;

        timeLeft--;

        if (timeLeft == 0)
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();

            this.Hide();

            AgeConfirmation _ageConfirmation = new AgeConfirmation();

            _ageConfirmation.ShowDialog();

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Above code is one loading form and load another form by the time is reached 0.

I have tried like this:

```
public class SystemManager
{
public static void LoadForm(Form _form = null, Form _loadForm = null)
{
   _form.Hide();

   _loadForm = new Form();

   _loadForm.ShowDialog();

   _form.Close();
}
}
```

and access it like this:

`SystemManager.LoadForm(this, AgeConfirmation);`

But it is throws the following error:

`'System.Windows.Forms.AgeConfirmation' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`

**My Question is: Create only one form (Loading Form), and access that Loading Form and by the time, the time reached 0, it will access different form.**

Your answer much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: `if (timeLeft == 0)` will always be true in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `_ageConfirmation`, which is the form object, not `AgeConfirmation` which is the form type.

i.e. `SystemManager.LoadForm(this, _ageConfirmation);`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself! I create a getter and setter int value and by using switch case and the code will be like this:

```
public class UserInformation
{
    public static int Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public partial class Loading : Form
{
    public Loading()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.timer1.Interval = SystemManager.RandomNumberGenerator(1000, 2000);

        this.timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(this.CheckTimer);
    }

    private void Loading_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Start();
    }

    private void CheckTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uint timeLeft = 1;

        timeLeft--;

        if (timeLeft == 0)
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();

            this.Hide();

            switch (UserInformation.Value)
            {
                case 0:
                AgeConfirmation _ageConfirmation = new AgeConfirmation();

                _ageConfirmation.ShowDialog();
                break;

                case 1:
                MainForm _mainForm = new MainForm();

                _mainForm.ShowDialog();
                break;

                case 2:
                Event _event = new Event();

                _event.ShowDialog();
                break;
            }

            this.Close();
        }
    }
}

private void AgeConfirmation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserInformation.Value = 1;
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        Loading _loading = new Loading();

        _loading.ShowDialog();

        this.Close();
    }

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserInformation.Value = 2;
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

        Loading _loading = new Loading();

        _loading.ShowDialog();

        this.Close();
    }
```

By the time the program runs, `UserInformation.Value` will be 0

Thank you very much for those who are replying to my question.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
_ageConfirmation.ShowDialog();
```

to

```
_ageConfirmation.Show();
```

Comment: Could you explain why you think this is an answer to this question?